# How can I check the functions-working in OPL, CPLEX?

Tags: cplex, opl

Let say I want to know the working of `forall` in opl, but because I cannot use `writeln` or `write` , Right? Then how can I verify it's working (Whether the logic is correct or not)? Is there any way, where I can check about the function working like in C (In any doubt, I can print the values anywhere)?

```
forall(u,v in  Node, k in users)
{
        forall(k in users) ((sum(w in Node)x[u][w][k] - sum(v in Node)x[v][u][k]) == ((u==x)?1:(u=[k]?-1:0)));
}
```

Now, how CPLEX engine understand this equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give a name to your constraint then you can see your constraints within the problem browser

See documentation

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_20.1.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/refoplide/topics/opl_gui_mainwin_pb.html